# Editing an elements attributes not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The following code is supposed to allow me to edit the attributes of the p element. The issue is that it remains the same. I added a test to change its contents at the end however it does nothing too. The text fields to edit the element appears and logs the new attributes but the element doesn't change

```
<body><p id=test>test</p>
<script>
var obj=document.getElementById("test")
var display="";
for(var i in obj){
    display+="<label for="+i+">"+i+"</label><input id="+i+" value='"+obj[i]+"' oninput='obj["+i+"]=this.value;
    console.log(obj["+i+"])'></input>"
}
document.body.innerHTML+=display
obj.innerHTML="hello"
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: First obvious issues: need quotations in `<p id="test">` and should end each javascript line with a semicolon (;)

Comment: First thing to fix is the fact that you are including a `console.log()` function call in your string and it's breaking the syntax. The code works after just this fix - [FIDDLE DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/hdy9jqv7/1/)

Comment: The quotes aren't needed as long as it has no spaces and apart from a few rare exceptions like for loops semicolons are optional

Comment: The console.log call is part of the string which is inserted into the Dom as the code to exercute when the oninput event fires

Answer (score 1):

This modified code should let you modify the `<p>` element attributes:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("test");
var display = "";
for (var i in obj) {
    display += "<label for='" + i + "'>" + i + "</label><input id='" + i + "' value='" + obj[i] + "' oninput='document.getElementById(\"test\")[\"" + i + "\"]=this.value;console.log(document.getElementById(\"test\")[\"" + i + "\"])'></input>";
}
document.body.innerHTML += display;
obj.innerHTML = "hello";
```

I basically fixed the quoting in the code. Also obj was losing its reference to the actual html element for some reason so used document.getElement... instead.

Comment: I've tried both and although the console is confirming the changes the display is static

Comment: Did you use updated code?  The element seems to update dynamically for me with this.

Comment: Yes I used this code in the answer than setAttribute

Comment: Try without setAttribute as it's not needed anymore with the updates I made

Comment: Its working now thank you, do you know why obj looses its reference to the element

Comment: Because you're reassigning `document.body.innerHTML`. That causes the DOM to be rebuilt from scratch, so the element that `obj` refers to no longer exists in the DOM.

Comment: If you want to append to the body without reparsing it, use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of assigning to `innerHTML`.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to put the inputs in another DIV, and set its innerHTML. That won't affect the `test` element.

Answer (score 0):

**It is not clear what you are trying to do, please specify what your desired result is.**

This code does affect DOM, but I am not sure if that is what you want your result to look like.

```html
    <body><p id=test>test</p>
    <script>

        var obj=document.getElementById("test").innerHTML
        var display="";

        for(var i in obj){
            display+="<label for=" + i + ">" + i +"</label><input id=" + i + " value='"+obj[i]+"' oninput='obj[" + i + "]=this.value;console.log(obj["+i+"])'></input>"
        }

        document.body.innerHTML+=display
        obj.innerHTML="hello"

    </script>
    </body>
```